# Is there CSS parent selector using braces for subclass shortcut?

Tags: css

I have a tonne of CSS styles like so:

```
.T .class1{...}
.T .class2{...}
.T .class3{...}
...etc
```

Is there any way to write this without writing the .T each time? Something like the way media queries work would be great:

```
.T{
    .class1{...}
    .class2{...}
    .class3{...}
    ...etc
}
```

Is something like this possible? If not, can we speculate as to the reasons why not?

Comment: It is, but in LESS or SASS.

Comment: For the record, I'm creating a touch stylesheet for a web app. The body tag has the class `T` so everything below it will be styled up for fat fingers

Comment: "If not, can we speculate as to the reasons why not?" No because Stack Overflow doesn't like speculative questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS does not support this. However, CSS *pre-processors* like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org) do.

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543020/is-there-css-parent-selector-using-braces-for-subclass-shortcut?noredirect=1#comment28996323_19543020)

Answer (score 1):

I've always wished CSS would structure that way, but sadly, it does not.

If all of the ".class1, .class2, etc." are to be styled the same, you can use a couple methods.

You could do something like:

```
.T .class1, .T .class2, .T .class3....{
    /* Your code here */
}
```

Or you could do something like this (depending on your applications):

```
.T *{
    /* Your code here */
}
```

The latter is less specific and would select everything inside of the .T element.

I'm assuming you need each "class1, class2" styled individually though, which would render these answers useless. At that point, you could use javascript to achieve this, though it is not as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating a touch stylesheet for a web app. The body tag has the
>   class T so everything below it will be styled up for fat fingers

You can write all styles in mobile.css and attach this file only for mobile device with JS

Comment: Yes I probably will do this - I'm mostly asking out of interest if this formatting is possible

Comment: You can use media-queries for styling your page for mobile

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can try the magic of:
 - SASS: http://sass-lang.com/
 - LESS: http://lesscss.org/

Once you start using them, just be careful not to go crazy when nesting selectors.